How do I limit a Microsoft desktop search to files on my computer?
When I want to search the web, I use a browser and my choice of search engine. When I use Microsoft desktop search I always want to search for files on my machine only. How do I limit  an MS-desktop search to local files? And can I make this the default?
Finally, I have often wished for a relatively thorough guide to MS-desktop search, including indexing, search options, and search command language, so I could answer questions like this myself. I have several such guides for Google searches, and have found them very useful. If anyone knows of such a guide fo MS-desktop search, and could point me toward it, I would be most grateful.

Does this answer your question? How do I limit Windows 11 desktop search to either filenames or file contents?

Remove one of the duplicate questions.

neither one has a suitable answer, so suggest to keep both up. Similar questions are "How to remove 'search the web' from windows search"

Yes, you can! To have MS-Search access only local files on Windows 11, open Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Search Permissions and under 'Cloud content Search' you'll find two check boxes. Uncheck them to have only local files appear in the search.
For a detailed guide, Microsoft actually provides some themselves.
Here is the Interactive Web Guide: https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-search
And here's a PDF/Printable Guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/pdf?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fmicrosoftsearch%2Ftoc.json
